# Alert box working at the time form submit using php

Tags: php

Alert box is not working at the time of submitting the form. Nevertheless, I get 'Customer Added Successfully' message in php. But I don't get an alert box. My code is given below:

```
   if($_POST['submit']) 
    { 
       $name=$_POST['name'];
       $phone_number=$_POST['phone_number'];
       $email=$_POST['email'];
       $sql="insert into
       customer set    name='$name',phone_number='$phone_number',email='$email'";
       $in executeUpdate($sql);
       if($in)
        {
         echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">".
         "alert('success');".
         "</script>";
          $sess_msg="Customer Added Successfully.";
          $_SESSION['sess_msg']=$sess_msg;

        }
      header("Location: addCustomer.php");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're sending a `Location:` header which results in a redirect, so the browser ignores any code in the page (including the javascript containing the alert).

You either need to remove the redirect (display the alert and a link to the next page), or display the alert on the target of the redirect. I'd go for the second option to avoid issues with reloads on a `POST`.